# php: hour and minute variables together

Tags: php, time

I have hour and time variable chosen by the client.
$Arrival_Hour - chosen in 01:00, 02:00  24 hrsformat
$Arrival_Min - chosen in 00:05, 00:10   5 min difference format.

Now i am writing

Hour:    `<?php echo $Arrival_Hour?>`

Min :    `<?php echo $Arrival_Min?>`

and it comes Hour:01:00 Min: 00:15

How i can write this in 01:15 format?

Hour: 01:15 - (hour and min together)

Thanks

Comment: Are you choosing date in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As quick workaround you could try:

Time: `<?php echo substr($Arrival_Hour, 0, 2) . ':'. substr($Arrival_Min, 3, 5);?>`

It's not perfect solution but you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
list($H, $Ht) = @explode(":", $Arrival_Hour);
list($Tt, $T) = @explode(":", $Arrival_Min);

echo $Time = $H.':'.$T;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hour: <?php echo date("H",strtotime($Arrival_Hour));?>

Min : <?php echo date("i",strtotime($Arrival_Min));?>
```